# Is there any Instagram Web API for the new version of the site?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

You're able to dm in the new version and i thought that there'd some simple GET and POST requests for that without getting access to the official instagram API. 

I don't want to use bots that emulate app or similar, cause i can get a ban for that.

Tried to look at XHR in network tab on dev tools (Google Chrome) but I've never done that before and I have some troubles with that. I see requests, headers, response (where are messages), but i can't define how to do that with python for example.

I'm looking for help with that or for any ready solutions (not nescessary for python, i think i can port them to python or just use the language an api was written for)

Edit:

link looks like this (for the inbox page):
`https://www.instagram.com/direct_v2/web/inbox/?persistentBadging=true&folder=0&limit=10&thread_message_limit=10`
and a ton of headers

Answer (score 1):

Instagram sends a request with cursor to load the direct messages data in chunks.

Its response has `prev_cursor` & `oldest_cursor`.

1. `oldest_cursor` value is the next cursor value you need to send for the next chunk of messages
2. When `prev_cursor` value becomes `MINCURSOR` it means that it is the last chunk means the first chunk of the message that has been initiated in the chat history.

I have been working on a script to unsend all the messages on Instagram DM. For deleting messages I need to get messages first, so I have written function which provides me all the messages.

> You can look at the repository https://github.com/pishangujeniya/instagram-helper
>
> For getting messages there is no limit in Instagram API requests. But for delete request, Instagram starts sending 429 Response Code i.e. Too Many Requests after we delete 83 messages in the single session. The solution to continue deleting is by logout and re-login after some time. But there also problems exist, if too many logouts and login were done, then Instagram blocks your account to log in for a particular period of time. (In my case I was blocked for 30 Minutes to log in while developing the script)

#### Update 20 April, 2020

> I updated the script with having delay between requests, so as to avoid 429 response, and it is working very fine as of now.

Comment: Just for Knowledge. Is it possible to get instagram like/follower without bot. Pure Coding (API or something) if you can help or suggest? Thanks

Comment: @afsarkhan10182 Yes, most probably it is possible, you need to have a look at the network trace for requests in a browser developer tools.

Comment: So i check the instagram like API(in browser network panel). So token and many other API get called. How should i proceed and reference if you can give?

Comment: Observe carefully which API has the data related to the task that you want to automate, and then take the reference code from my repository and try it by yourself.

Comment: I check your code. So you have automated using python by getting the response from API by passing header which is required to get the data right?

if i follow your method is there any chance of getting blocked by instagram account as i want to login using insta credentials? any type of help will be appreciated Pishang

Comment: Nope Your account won't get blocked. If you attempt so many times login in single day then it will block for certain hours. Better don't login again and again. In the code you can even skip the python code, basic JS file code you can inject using chrome developer tools and run those respective functions and it will work.